# Wordpress custom login template

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom page in wordpress named custom-login.php and then I set this template to login-chat page from wordpress admin panel, when I visited login-chat page I got login form, I puted my login details and then it redirected me to chat page. But the problem is I can access chat page without doing login.

Code of custom-login.php

```
<?php
$args = array(
'echo'           => true,
'redirect' => site_url( '/chat/ ' ),
'form_id'        => 'loginform',
'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
'label_log_in'   => __( 'Log In' ),
'id_username'    => 'user_login',
'id_password'    => 'user_pass',
'id_remember'    => 'rememberme',
'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
'remember'       => true,
'value_username' => '',
'value_remember' => false
); 

wp_login_form($args); 

?>
```

Does anyone know, how to prevent chat page from being accessible without login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your chat page template insert the following:

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { die(); } ?>
```

This function returns false, if the current user is not logged in: [is_user_logged_in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

Alternatively, if you do not want to modify the chat template, you can fire the login check at page load. Add this to the **functions.php** of your theme:

```
// 'template_redirect' is fired before the template is rendered
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_access');

function check_access(){
   // only block the access for the chat page with the slug 'chat'
   if(is_page('chat')){
       // if the user is not logged in: abort
       if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { die(); }
   }
}
```